# How to rename multiple files using Windows Explorer in Windows10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Let’s start with an example, let's say we have a directory `C:\dev\to-delete`
Under this directory you can find a file:

```
Blah.txt
```

And one folder called `Foo`
Under the `Foo` folder there is one more file:

```
Blah4.txt
```

I want to rename all the files in the directory `C:\dev\to-delete` and all subfolders which start with the phrase “blah.txt” to “newname”. To do this I just type the phrase “blah.txt” in the Windows Explorer Search bar, on the top right of the screen and in the result I'm getting all 2 .txt files.
Then I can select them all(ctrl+a) and click F2 to set a new name “newname”. And now the problem appears. All the files have been renamed to the “newname (1).txt” instead of just “newname.txt”.
Can anybody tell me how to get rid of this “(1)” from the new name I gave to all the files? If this is not possible I'm looking for some alternative solution.
Cheers